# How can I run a HIT Task with ParlAi and MTurk

Tags: amazon-web-services, bots, mechanicalturk, parlai

I tried to follow this tutorial on publishing a HIT Task on MTurk using ParlAI: 
[how to setup a task with parlAI](https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-training-ai-bots-to-chat-using-mturk-and-facebooks-parlai-42af81475c6c)

The tutorial says that I should run the following code in order to run the task on sandbox:

```
$ python run.py -nh 2 -r 0.05 --sandbox --verbose
```

Normally, it should then download the dataset that has been specified in the agents.py file. But when I run this in powershell, the following error message occurs:

```
PS C:\py3\ParlAI\parlai\mturk\tasks\model_evaluator> python run.py -nh 2 -r 
0.05 --sandbox --verbose
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run.py", line 6, in <module>
from parlai.core.params import ParlaiParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parlai'
PS C:\py3\ParlAI\parlai\mturk\tasks\model_evaluator>
```

It says that module parlai is missing. How can I make it work?

Thanks for your answer!

Best regards

Rainer

Answer (score 2):

This error means that ParlAI just hasn't been installed to your python path yet (`python setup.py develop` in the ParlAI home directory).

However, note that ParlAI doesn't officially support windows, so you're likely to run into further errors after that.

(The ParlAI team usually responds pretty quickly if you open issues on the Github page if you have questions directly for them.)